# scala easiest way to convert any type of object to String?

Tags: scala

In scala , what is easiest way to convert ANY type of object to String ? in java, I always use String concatenation to achieve this, like

```
String msg = myLong+""
val msg : String = myLong+"" //not work
```

**Update**: it should work:

```
 val start:Long = System.currentTimeMillis
  dataMap += ("start" -> (start+""))
```

but this way will not work

```
dataMap += ("start" -> start+"")
```

Thanks.

Comment: that should work. What error do you get?

Comment: Has no one heard of `toString` ?

Comment: `dataMap += ("start" -> start.toString)` is a cleaner/clearer representation of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that

```
val msg : String = myLong+"" //not work
```

doesn't work?

Here's what I get in my scala REPL:

```
scala> val myLong = 100L
myLong: Long = 100

scala> val msg : String = myLong+""
msg: String = 100
```

You can definitely do string concatenation in Scala for any object. I like to just call toString on it though.